# I'm having an issue playing .mp4 urls in my tvos app

Tags: swift, avplayer, tvos

Recently my tvOS app stopped working because of a message tha I can see in the logs:

```
[avas] AVAudioSessionUtilities.h:112:GetProperty: AudioSessionGetProperty ('caft') failed with error: '!ini'
[avas] AVAudioSessionUtilities.h:127:GetProperty_DefaultToZero: AudioSessionGetProperty ('caft') failed with error: '!ini'
```

Actually, it was working before and stopped working about a month ago.

I know this is related to AVAudioSession, I've tried many ways but still not working.

I'm able to use other 3rd party players such as but not AVPlayer

It works. on the simulator but the device! device displays a red icon on the bottom left of the screen and logs the mentioned 2 lines.

Any help or recommendation is much appreciated.

Thanks